# How to define a class instance of type_synonym?

Tags: isabelle

`type` is an instance of `semilattice_sup` class:

```
datatype type = BType | IType | AType

instantiation type :: semilattice_sup
begin
end
```

I'm trying to declare `type × bool` type as an instance of this class too:

```
type_synonym stype = "type × bool"

instantiation stype :: semilattice_sup
begin
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
Bad type name: "stype"
```

How to define a class instance of type_synonym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. In fact, there *is* already an instance of `semilattice_sup` for the product type in `Product_Order` in HOL-Library, so if `type` has an `semilattice_sup` instance, then so does `type × bool` (if you include `Product_Order`. Note that this is the pointwise order, not the lexicographic one.

If you need another order or something very specific to your type, you can also define an entirely new type with `typedef`:

```
typedef type' = "UNIV :: (type × bool) set"
  by auto
```

That gives you morphisms `Abs_type'` and `Rep_type'` to convert between `type'` and `type × bool`, and since this is a completely new type, you can provide type class instances for it.

For the sake of completeness, type classes are implemented with locales, and you can interpret the type class locale manually, giving you all the definitions and lemmas from the type class, but of course, the integration with the type class framework will not work. For one, `type × bool` will not be of the sort `semilattice_sup`. Still, occasionally, this can be a viable solution:

```
interpretation type_bool: semilattice_sup mysup myle myless
proof
```

(where `mysup`, `myle`, `myless` are `sup`, `≤`, `<` for `type × bool`, which you have to provide and then prove that they fulfil the axioms. The names are, of course, completely arbitrary, including `type_bool`)