# Instantiate typeclass over type_synonym

Tags: types, isabelle, theorem-proving

In my theory developent I have one concept "bar" of function for a bunch of types (say, bar_atom, bar_clause, etc.), so I figured I'd abstract that out using a typeclass for readability (since I'd rather just type "bar" everywhere and have the type system figure out which function to use).

I tried the following:

```
theory Sat
 imports Main
begin

type_synonym atom = nat

class foo =
  fixes bar :: "'a ⇒ nat"

instantiation atom :: foo begin

end

end
```

Isabelle gives an error at "instantiation atom", as follows:

```
Bad type name: "Sat.atom"⌂
```

I know this is already partially answered in [How to define a class instance of type_synonym?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708423/how-to-define-a-class-instance-of-type-synonym). However, I was hoping that problem was caused by the fact a that there was already a pre-existing typeclass. In my case it's a custom and completely local typeclass, so I was hoping in that case a typeclass over a type synonym is no problem. But I can't get it to work. I wouldn't mind inlining the type synonym, but that doesn't seem to work either. It only seems to work for primitive types like "nat" and "int".

The answer says I could also define my own type, but I'd like my base types to stay simple if I can. I'm assuming the proofs will be more automated if I stick to type synonyms like `atom = nat` and such, but maybe that's overly cautious? Maybe when this theory development is finished I'd like to abstract the entire thing over the types used (since most of the type synonyms can be opaque, I think, as long as equality is defined) and then this is more relevant, but at the moment as just a proof of concept that's not necessary.

Comment: One comment (as someone who has a full entailment library https://www.isa-afp.org/theories/ordered_resolution_prover/#Clausal_Logic.html): "have the type system figure out which function to use" will not happen on any the basic lemmas (just think of `I |= N \union N' <--> I |=N & I |= N'`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't fully understand, sorry. What I am looking for is to simulate function overloading in java (which allows you to have methods with the same name, but different signatures) using typeclasses. Are you saying this will not work for basic lemmas somehow? I expect that once isabelle typed a typeclass function call, it can unfold it using the corresponding instance, no? That should then work fine for both basic and complicated lemmas...?

Comment: In my experience, it won't work as you epxect, because there is too much ambiguity in all your lemmas (lemmas about entailment on one clause and entailment of many clauses behave very differently). So you will end up with adding annotation on types anyhow.

Comment: I see what you mean, especially when the types of a few calls start interacting with eachother... That's too bad. What do you do to work around it? I've taken to using single letter subscripts to indicate if the functions takes a [f]ormula, [c]lause, etc. It's a bit annoying to type but works well.

Comment: Same here: ⊨, ⊨s, ⊨p, ... (with the additional 'm' for multisets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this does not work. You can either choose to instantiate the class with nat, or to define a wrapper type. If it’s your own class, I’d recommend the former.

Comment: Okay, so instantiating the typeclass for "nat list" will not work either? Is this becuase "nat list" is not a concrete type?

Comment: If you have a link or source to share that maybe further explains this I'd be very thankful and interested!

Comment: No, you cannot instantiate for composite types like nat list either. I’m sure this is described in the Isabelle reference, but I don’t think that’s particularly helpful for beginners. (I’m unaware of such a source.)